# How to take previous non-null value in sequence?

Tags: sql, presto, trino

DB is Presto. Say I have a table `{id dim1, dim2, seq, value}`. `seq` is the sequence number for for `value`, and `value` contains NULLs. I have:

```
select
id,
dim1,
dim2,
seq,
value,
"value_backfilled" -- Want to compute this
from table
group by id, dim1, dim2
order by id, dim1, dim2, seq
```

In the select I want "backfill" `value` with the last non-null value in the sequence.
For example, in a particular grouping, the `values` are [1, null, null, null, 2, null, null, 3, null, null, null], I want it to be [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presto supports `IGNORE NULLS`, so you seem to want:

```
select lag(value ignore nulls) over (order by id)
```

If the value is always increasing, you can also use `max()`:

```
select max(value) over (order by id)
```

Note:  If you want this per dimension combinations, then you would add `partition by`.

Comment: I had to switch the syntax to `select lag(value) ignore nulls over (order by id)` for this to work